# Slurm is making my python script wait in running status

Tags: slurm

When I submit the following Slurm file with `sbatch`, the job has an immediately running status. However, the Python script runs after about 10 minutes. Also, I tried the same with `srun` command, and after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, again `srun` runs after 10 minutes. What is the reason for this waiting?

Slurm file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=Van-BIG_lr
#SBATCH --nodes=1
source activate open-mmlab-swim
python den.py
```

Comment: Maybe it's the "source activate" command that is taking 10 minutes.  You could add some commands to output timestamp info before and after the "source activate" command to see if that's where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

How are you detecting that the script is running? Sometimes Slurm can be configured to update logs periodically, and you may be experiencing this.